# how to bypass rules in .htaccess when a condition is met?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a bunch rules in my .htaccess

I want to apply a new rule: 
if the url is:

```
http://www.example.com/documentation/invoices/....
```

I just want to keep the url as it is, it means: I want to bypass all rules

Any idea ?

Comment: `Any idea ?` Yes, but you have not provided any rules. How are we supposed to know where to help you put the condition when you haven't shown any code.

Comment: There are like 1500 rules: what I try to do is: if this condition is met, then DO NOTHING, bypass all rules : that will be the simplest way !

Comment: Look for the REQUEST_URI then if it matches, stop processing

Comment: thanks but do you mind to write that rule ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided no code there is no way to know if there will be a conflict. However this would go above all the other rewrite rules under RewriteEngine On.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/documentation/invoices
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```